# ruby net sftp : fastest way to get list of files

Tags: ruby, net-ssh, net-sftp

I am using ruby Net-sftp gem,I need to download large number of small files before I download I need to make sure to get a list of files in the given directory.
In order to do that I am using `sftp.dir.entries('folder path').size` to get list of file count but doing this operation on more than 10,000 files taking too much time(even hours) is there a better way to do this ?
even I tried using `ssh.exec!("ls -l")` this is also slow.
I am tring to connect to windows box which is windows server 2008 R2

Answer (score 5):

to download a series of files with validations, i would do something like the following:

```
Net::SFTP.start(ftp_host, user, :password => password) do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.entries('/path/to/folder').each do |remote_file|
    if passes_validation?(remote_file)
      file_data = sftp.download!('/path/to/folder' + '/' + remote_file.name)
      local_file = File.open('/path/to/local', 'wb')
      local_file.print file_data
      local_file.close
    end
  end
end
```

one thing to remember when using this approach is that there are differences in SFTP server protocols which affect how many attributes will be accessible for `remote_file`; you can check what protocol you are working with by calling `sftp.protocol` after opening the connection.

alternatively, if you wanted to try to pass validations as part of your query to the SFTP, you could try `.glob("/path/to/folder", "*.ext")` instead of `.entries` if your validation is based on the file extension, though i can't speak for how it will work speed-wise (documentation [here](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-sftp/classes/Net/SFTP/Operations/Dir.html)). in theory, it *could* speed-up the query (less data to return), but as it involves more work up-front, i'm not certain it will help.

i'm running my script from a VirtualBox running Ubuntu 12 with 2 GB of RAM dedicated (host is Windows 7), and connecting to a server with Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 installed, running SolarWind for the SFTP portion; Ruby 1.9.3p392, Net-SFTP 2.1.2 and Net-SSH 2.6.8. with those tech specs, i roughly average 78 files a minute (though that is without validations).

Comment: `"i need to make sure i get a list of files in the given directory" - can you explain why you need this?` I need to run some validation before download